# How to set key_ops in generating JWK using java script?

Tags: javascript, parameters, jwk, keyset

I want to generate JWK with parameters using JavaScript. Following is the code I used to generate JWK

```
var JA = java.util;
var JWKgen = Packages.com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.gen;
var Keys = Packages.com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.KeyUse;
var ops = Packages.com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.KeyOperation;
var alg = Packages.com.nimbusds.jose.Algorithm;

var RSAKeyjwk = JWKgen.RSAKeyGenerator(3072)
.keyUse(Keys.SIGNATURE) 
.keyID(JA.UUID.randomUUID().toString())
.algorithm(alg("RS384"))
.issueTime(new Date()) 
.generate();
```

I have added the keyUse, KeyId, algorithm as per the following link
https://javadoc.io/static/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/6.7/com/nimbusds/jose/jwk/gen/JWKGenerator.html#keyOperations-java.util.Set-

I want to add "key_ops":["verify"],"ext": true in the JWK. I tried following syntax

keyOperations(Set <KeyOperation) - Method in class com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.gen.JWKGenerator
Sets the operations (key_ops) of the JWK.

```
.keyOperations(Set(ops['VERIFY'])). 
.keyOperations(Set(ops.VERIFY))
.keyOperations(Set(ops("VERIFY")))
```

I am getting the following error

TypeError: Set objects may not be constructed using "new".
TypeError: Set objects may not be constructed using "new".

Java constructor for "com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.KeyOperation" with arguments "string" not found.

Please help me on how to add the key_ops parameter.

Thanks

Comment: the code you've shown ... is that javascript? the fact that you linked to some java site suggests not ... do you know the difference?

Comment: I refer to the Java library: Take a look at the source code or the corresponding tests, there you can see how `Set<KeyOperation>`  / `keyOperations()` is used: https://github.com/felx/nimbus-jose-jwt/blob/master/src/test/java/com/nimbusds/jose/jwk/KeyOperationTest.java

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved with the help of my colleague. Here it is

```
var JA = java.util;

const verify = JA.Set(ops.parse(['verify']));


var RSAKeyjwk = JWKgen.RSAKeyGenerator(3072)
.keyUse(Keys.SIGNATURE)
.keyID(JA.UUID.randomUUID().toString())
.algorithm(alg("RS384"))
.keyOperations(verify)
.issueTime(new Date())
.generate();

logger.info(RSAKeyjwk);
```

still I couldnt add "ext": true no methods available in JWK gen.